# Configure proxy for APT?

Tags: apt

I need to configure proxy. There wasn't `apt.conf` file in `/etc/apt/` so I've created it using `nano`.

But I don't understand what I need to write there. I've written
`http_proxy = http://lgn:pwd@192.168.1.254:8080/` there and then restarted `networking`. But when I try to `apt-get update` - it doesn't work.

Actually, I don't understand what port and IP I should write in `apt.conf` file (there was example with `192.168.1.254` IP and `8080` port, so I decided to use them).

Comment: There is a change in proxy settings to get work in corporate proxy in ubuntu visit https://github.com/navinas33/docker_ubuntu.git it works...

Answer (score 162, accepted):

To use a proxy, you need a proxy server. The IP and port have to be from this proxy server. Login and pwd must be your user and password on the proxy server (if the proxy requires login).

From [help.ubuntu.com site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto/#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy):

> APT configuration file method
>
> This method uses the apt.conf file which is found in your /etc/apt/ directory. This method is useful if you only want apt-get (and not other applications) to use a http-proxy permanently.
>
> On some installations there will be no apt-conf file set up. Edit apt-conf file (or create a new one if you have no one yet) using the editor of your choice.
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
> ```
>
> Add this line to your /etc/apt/apt.conf file (substitute your details for yourproxyaddress and proxyport).
>
> ```
> Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
> ```
>
> Save the apt.conf file.

If your proxy needs a login/password, substitute:

```
"http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

with:

```
"http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

using username and password from the proxy server.

Comment: Adding a separate local file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` is preferrable so you don't have to edit the system's basic configuration files.  That way, if they are updated in a subsequent package version, you don't have to merge in your local changes by hand.

Comment: Is there a proxy conf file on the user directory?

Comment: This answer needs an update: gksudo is obsolete. Consider suggesting other non-GUI editor or `sudo -H` instead of gksudo if using gedit or similar.

Answer (score 56):

This is a more general answer along with apt config.

As there are a lot of places to configure proxy settings, it might get confusing at beginning. Let me summarize some things and suggest some good practices.

#### For console programs

Ex: `wget`, `git` and almost every console application which connects to internet.

If you want to configure proxy every time you run your commands then **set the environment variables** using following commands.

```sh
export http_proxy="http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/"
export ftp_proxy="http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/"
```

Else if you want to use the same settings every time for all users, then:

##### Configure in bashrc

```sh
$ nano /etc/bash.bashrc
export http_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
export ftp_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
```

To apply user-wide use `~/.bashrc`.

##### Configure in `/etc/environment`

```sh
$ nano /etc/environment
https_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/" 
ftp_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/" ...
```

##### Configure using GUI

Open the network settings and set your system-wide network proxy.

Network → Network proxy → Configure → Apply system-wide.

But this might not be useful if you have authentication for the proxy.

#### For apt

You need to do some extra work for apt, as apt doesn't care about the proxy environment variables.

```sh
$ nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT";
```

---

For everything out of this scope, there will likely be an option to configure proxy settings in the application itself.

Comment: the config in /etc/environment is very important because if you just setup the http_proxy var for your user, when you go into sudo mode (for stuff like 'sudo apt-get update'), the terminal usually does not preserve the current environment vars ; very important to test your settings : sudo echo $http_proxy

Comment: `HTTP_PROXY` (in upper case) appears to be the standard name for that variable, though many programs will fall back to the lower case version. `https_proxy` (note lower case) is the correct capitalisation for that, but you'd never use it alone, as you do in your `/etc/environment` above. (I think the `s` is a typo.)

Comment: What is the reason for APT to require additional configuration of proxy? Why doesn't it just obey with /etc/environment?

Comment: @cjs agreed, the 's' in `https://` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 25):

Something like the following should work:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://lgn:pwd@192.168.1.254:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://lgn:pwd@192.168.1.254:8080/";
```

Comment: Is there is difference what port and ip to use?

Comment: Well, yes, you need to put in the correct details for the proxy you want to use of course.

Comment: er...ip - it is router's ip? I mean this ip I used from example but all router's setting I configure in browser using `192.168.1.1` ip. I should use .1? and login and password should be ubuntu's root or router's?

Comment: Do you even know what you're doing? How do you know you need to use a proxy if you don't know the details for it?

Comment: It's my university's laboratory work(simple task). I can configure dhcp, dns, ssh but I don't know how to configure proxy, what ip and port to use.

Comment: Then ask your teacher. This is not a "do my homework for me" site.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Why do you assume that getting a Linux machine to work in a university lab environment is a "homework assignment"? It's just as likely that this is not a class on Linux network configuration and he's just trying to use Linux in an environment where most people use Windows and things "just work." In which case, your response is explicitly discouraging people from using Linux instead of Windows.

Answer (score 14):

What you can do is also try to run command with `sudo -E`, which will take the environment settings. It seems to work for me when I try to update, add-apt-repository, and install.
Example:

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:xxxxx
```

According to @David Foerster this only works for manual interaction using shell, but it won't work on automated tasks and services invoking Apt without user interaction.

Comment: That won't help with automated tasks and services invoking Apt without user interaction though.

Comment: Thank you for the notice, I will add your comment to the response.

Comment: This solved it for me!

Answer (score 7):

If you need to use apt behind a proxy, probably everything else also needs the proxy config.
I like to manage my proxy settings in one place, which would be the environment variable.

For that I create a `/etc/profiles.d/99-proxy.sh`, that contains the necessary proxy settings (like larent described):

```
export http_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftps_proxy=$http_proxy
```

that way, all users on that machine have access to the proxy. (don't forget `chmod a+x`)

When you use apt or apt-get as a user, that user is able to use sudo.
Like Frank Qiu described, sudo does not pass environment variables.
For that you can add

```
Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

to (e.g.)

```
/etc/sudoers.d/00-environment
```

or directly into the

```
/etc/sudoers
```

file. That way you only have to manage the proxy settings in one place.

Comment: `/etc/environment` or whatever other file PAM (pam_env module) use to set up the environment is more reliable - it does not need a shell to start...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a proxy just in one case, [you can use](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/apt.8.html) `[-o=config_string]`:

```
apt -o acquire::http::proxy="http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport"
```

Note the `=`. The option is case-insensitive.

Also, if you have repos using https on your `sources.list` you may want to add `-o acquire::https::proxy=false`.

Already mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063312/349837).

Answer (score 0):

The original question might be in wrong direction. I believe you want to setup a proxy server in Linux ?

Well that is completely different than wanting to use a existing proxy from Linux environment.

If your question is the first one then use any third party services to configure a proxy server in Linux. An example could be squid.

Simple commands to install squid:

```
$ sudo apt-get install squid3
```

Then edit the configuration to allow the Local Net (in this case your own machine). 
    $ sudo vi /etc/squid3/squid.conf

Add/Edit the following lines:

```
http_access allow local_net
acl local_net src 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```

**Assuming your IP for the Linux machine is in 192.168.1/24 block.**

Comment: Probably most readers of this question already installed squid ;), also set the `http[s]_proxy` ENV variables, and now wonder, why APT still doesn't work. But if you're getting HTTP 403 from everything except the machine with `squid` - do look once again for all occurences of the word `deny` which are not commented. (especially with `http_access` on the same line.