# Why is apt-get always using proxy, although no proxy is configured?

Tags: apt, proxy

I'm trying to disable the proxy for `apt-get` but it seems like `apt-get` gets it's proxy configuration from somewhere else other than `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, because although the `apt.conf` file is empty (and the system proxy set to `None`) it's still trying to connect to the proxy.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'm using a script to replace different configuration files in order to easily switch between proxy and non-proxy environements. The problem was that I replaced the proxy apt.conf file with an empty apt.conf file, which apt then ignored.

*Works for current latest Ubuntu as well.*

If the proxy conf does not exist, create it:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxy.conf
```

Then add the following two lines:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "false";
Acquire::https::Proxy "false";
```

Comment: It`s work! Disabled the Proxy with apt.conf.

Comment: Im my case worked simply removing 95proxy.conf file from /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ but better to explicit :D thank you.

Comment: where is this apt.conf file?

Comment: @LostCrotchet `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

Comment: This worked like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04. Somehow my apt proxy setting was changed even though the network proxy was unchanged. This solution is the only way out.

Answer (score 27):

If you do not want `apt-get` to use a proxy,
use `apt-get` as:

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=false <update/install>
```

Comment: Most underrated answer ever.

Comment: Best if you just want a temporary one-time solution.

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes, there are proxy environment variables that are still set.

To find out, do the following command:

```
env | grep proxy
```

If you see some output, for example:

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1234/
```

Then you'll need to unset this variable.

To do so, execute the following command:

```
unset http_proxy
```

Follow the same approach for all the other entries, such as `https_proxy`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately both the http and the https proxy are empty :\

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Although I doubt it, but maybe the variable is `HTTP_PROXY` (all caps), so try `env | grep -i proxy` `(-i` meaning "case insensitive"), and see if there's any output; it's worth a try =/. Also, can you do `grep -iR proxy /etc/apt/`? This searches for the word proxy in all files under `/etc/apt/`, because the proxy is sometimes set in a file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

Comment: It also doesn't have to do with proxy being all caps. Executing the grep command also didn't reveal any other file that contains a proxy configuration.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I'm using a script to switch all configuration files for proxies. The problem was that I replaced the apt.conf with an empty file. Apt then obviously always loaded the last proxy configuration, because the proxy value was not set to false. Thanks anyway for your efforts!

Comment: Maype the proxy env has setting in `/etc/environment` , so we can looking for here.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't only one place where apt-get read configuration files. You should run `grep -i proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*` and it will give you the exact file that has the proxy settings (this is just an example running with `update` instead `proxy`:

```
grep -i update /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-show-versions:// When Apt's cache is updated (i.e. apt-cache update)
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit:// Whenever dpkg is called we might have different updates
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit:// i.e. if an user removes a package that had an update
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit:"/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 1 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null";
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit:// When Apt's cache is updated (i.e. apt-cache update)
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit:"/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 1 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null";
```

Comment: This is not enough, the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` also can contain Proxy information. Also it may be written with capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the environment variable http_proxy is set to some proxy. try clearing the variable (or at least look if it has a value)

Answer (score 2):

Stupid way of making it work is disable the proxy for a while using `system settings > Network` .

Or remove the proxy config from `/etc/environment` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

[image]

And add the manual proxy config back once you need proxy back.

Comment: This worked and is really simple to follow :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, no proxy variables were set in the environment, and no proxy was set at the system level. However, a file `01proxy` was present in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` which contained the line `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://PROXY:PORT";`. Commenting the line with `#` (or deleting the file) worked for me. This means that other files in `apt.conf` and `apt.conf.d` may contain proxy settings and I'd suggest greping `proxy` (with `-i` flag) information from those two folders to know if the `apt` service uses one.

Note that [@Prashant Adlinge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344802/why-is-apt-get-always-using-proxy-although-no-proxy-is-configured/1063312#1063312) answer always works in that case as it bypasses any configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

you should bypass all proxy settings:

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=false -o Acquire::https::proxy=false -o Acquire::ftp::Proxy=false update
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=false -o Acquire::https::proxy=false -o Acquire::ftp::Proxy=false install xxx
```