# Could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: networking, apt, updates

I am trying to install / update some packages (in this case `libnlopt-dev`). When I type `sudo apt-get update` I get this:

```
Err:1 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
  Could not resolve host: deb.opera.com
Err:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
  Could not resolve 'repository.spotify.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve host: deb.opera.com
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'repository.spotify.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

pinging, for example, `archive.ubuntu.com` works just fine. I'm also able to browse the internet without issues.

Here is the output of running `host -v archive.ubuntu.com`:

```
Trying "archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48628
;; flags: qr ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archive.ubuntu.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
archive.ubuntu.com.     505     IN      A       91.189.88.149

Received 52 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 13 ms
Trying "archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27582
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archive.ubuntu.com.            IN      AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
archive.ubuntu.com.     600     IN      AAAA    2001:67c:1360:8001::21
archive.ubuntu.com.     600     IN      AAAA    2001:67c:1560:8001::11
archive.ubuntu.com.     600     IN      AAAA    2001:67c:1560:8001::14
archive.ubuntu.com.     600     IN      AAAA    2001:67c:1360:8001::17

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             352     IN      NS      ns3.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.             352     IN      NS      ns2.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.             352     IN      NS      ns1.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.             352     IN      NS      ns4.p27.dynect.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.p27.dynect.net.     41193   IN      A       208.78.70.27
ns2.p27.dynect.net.     41193   IN      A       204.13.250.27
ns3.p27.dynect.net.     41193   IN      A       208.78.71.27
ns4.p27.dynect.net.     41193   IN      A       204.13.251.27

Received 298 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 54 ms
Trying "archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21583
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archive.ubuntu.com.            IN      MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             300     IN      SOA     ns1.canonical.com. hostmaster.canonical.com. 2016102809 10800 3600 604800 3600

Received 97 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 35 ms
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check if you have enabled apt-proxy

Comment: What happens if you do the `sudo apt-get update` _immediately after_ the `host -v`?

Comment: @zwets exactly the same thing

Comment: @Anwar how do I do that? `grep -ri proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*` returns nothing, if that helps.

Comment: @arman check it http://askubuntu.com/questions/344802/why-is-apt-get-always-using-proxy-although-no-proxy-is-configured

Comment: @Anwar ok so doing `sudo echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"false\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95disable-proxy` and then rebooting seems to have resolved it. But why? Can I somehow find out what's setting the proxy up in the first place?

Comment: @arman that's another topic. you might have installed something or configured. That depends on how you were using it

Comment: @Anwar ok, thanks! I haved asked another question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/842800/why-do-i-have-to-disable-a-proxy-in-apt-conf-d