# apt-get installs can't connect to mirror

Tags: apt, package-management

Getting the following error attempting to run an apt-get update in prep for a package install:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:2 http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease                               
  Could not connect to mirror.picosecond.org:80 (2001:470:1:12e::133). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirror.picosecond.org:80 (184.105.204.133), connection timed out
Err:3 http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to mirror.picosecond.org:http:
Err:4 http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to mirror.picosecond.org:http:
Err:5 http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to mirror.picosecond.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to mirror.picosecond.org:80 (2001:470:1:12e::133). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirror.picosecond.org:80 (184.105.204.133), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to mirror.picosecond.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to mirror.picosecond.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to mirror.picosecond.org:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Doing a bit of googling this seems to be most commonly related to proxy settings.  I have installed a proxy via Firefox since I can last recall running `apt-get update` successfully, but it's not currently active, and even when it is, I'm not seeing any proxy specified:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/etc/apt$ env | grep -i proxy
chris@chris-X1C6:/etc/apt$
```

I've also tried running `apt-get update` setting the proxy option to false as described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/345211/951772) (as I don't appear to have an apt.conf file):

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::Proxy="false"
```

with the same results.

Any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix.

Comment: Is it a mirror?  I didn't find it in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: Should be, I haven't changed any of the default config settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Choose download from main server.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

I don't think it is a proxy problem.

> Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Connect to your ppa is possible.

Comment: Weird, that appeared to fix it--update now runs.  The picosecond mirror was one of the dropdown options, along with 'Main Server' and 'Server for United States'.  Any ideas about how the picosecond mirror would have been added?  Like I mentioned, I haven't manually messed with any of the mirror settings.