# proxy disconfiguration after using privoxy

Tags: proxy, privoxy

Used privoxy for some time, and uninstalled it afterwards. Now software installation from the terminal is using the privoxy data, with messages like:

`Failed to fetch http://...  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8118 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)`

Any idea on how to restore the previous configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The proxy settings are stored in the `http_proxy` environment variable.

Check your startup configuration files like `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`, etc. and look for a line like this, remove it, then log out and log back in again:

```
export http_proxy="http://host:port"
```

For a temporary solution, you can use this command from a terminal:

```
unset http_proxy
```

Comment: Already did the editing, and had deleted `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` from `/etc/environment`, but stil getting the same error message.  'unset' has worked, but I understand it isn't a final solution.

Comment: Did you try logging out? Maybe a reboot would help?

Comment: yep, rebooting didn't help.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt