# apt-get - where are the sources stored?

Tags: apt, updates

I was trying to update `apt-get` and I keep getting 404 errors - I assumed it was the fault of my proxy, which has been causing errors in `wget` and in the browser, but upon visiting one of the links that reported an error, I found that it was trying to download a "Sources" file which on the server was actually stored as "Sources.bz2"

I was able to get the list of sources from this - where should I put it so that `apt-get` will use them?

EDIT: current sources.list (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Current apt.conf

```
Acquire::http::User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://129.###.###.###:80";
```

Comment: You have to configure apt to use a proxy - http://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt

Comment: Post your current `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @muru I put it up, thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've tried this in several ways, both with the "$http_proxy" variable and through the apt.conf file. I also changed the user agent (because I had to do that for my browser to get through the proxy). It's a corporate environment, so I can't change the proxy.

Comment: Talk to your IT dept for support on the proxy ;)

Answer (score 8):

Your `sources.list` is stored at `/etc/apt/` folder. To see and edit them you can run:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

To edit that file run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

Your PPAs are stored to:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Though **do mention** when editing those files manually make sure you know what you are doing/editing that this/those repos/sources that you're adding will definitely work with your current distro otherwise you can break/damage your `apt`. Usually when adding new repositories you should run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository some:ppa
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean this:
`/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Well yes and no - this list is what failed when I called `sudo apt-get update`. I decided to try to download the sources the UPDATE was downloading, and was hoping to learn where to put them, since my update functionality isn't really working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ron This is an attempt to answer the question so it is an *answer*, although it isn't of very high quality it is still *an answer* ;)

Comment: @Seth The author is *not sure*, so it is *not* an *answer* but fits better in *requesting clarification* (as in *did you mean this?*). And someone else did feel this is the right comment.