# "does not have a Release File" yet cannot find reference to source or ppa (Couchdb)

Tags: ppa, 21.04, couchdb

I tried unsuccessfully to install CouchDB on Ubuntu 21, but now I get this error on apt-get update which seems preventing me from installing anything else on my system.

```
d@mypc:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:2 https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb hirsute InRelease                                      
Hit:3 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                 
Err:4 https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 35.160.64.110 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The weird thing is /etc/apt/sources.list is empty as I have already removed the couchdb source I tried to add earlier.

Where is my system referencing "https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb" and how do I remove it?

Comment: Look for the corresponding file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Comment: Thankyou!!  Didn't know about that directory

Comment: Seems ok to close this questions as a duplicate of [apt-get - where are the sources stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640964/apt-get-where-are-the-sources-stored)

Comment: Answered by mook765: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359507/does-not-have-a-release-file-yet-cannot-find-reference-to-source-or-ppa-couch?noredirect=1#comment2329066_1359507

Comment: yes it can close but I don't know how to 'close' i Tried making "Answer Your Question" with links to mook's comment but it just converted it to a comment . 

anyway @N0rbert no I reviewed that thread in my troubleshooting nowhere does it mention sources.list.d which is what/where my problem was.   I didn't have any ppa installed so there was nothing to purge. 

It might be a dupe of the one mook suggested but it is a little different context, in mine I wanted to know where to remove sources but the other thread was about resolving them; but anyway that's that!