# Install apache2 and tomcat7 without apt-get (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: server, software-installation, apache2, tomcat7

How can I install apache2 and tomcat7 without using `apt-get`? The only command I'm allowed to use to download stuff is `wget`.

I download apache2 from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apache2. Downloaded apache2-bin as well. However, I can't figure out how to install it. I get .deb packages and since I'm new to Linux, I really don't know how to proceed.

For tomcat7, it's a bit different since I can't find tomcat7 in Ubuntu's package website. So I downloaded it from here: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi. But that comes in a tar.gz file.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you install .deb by typing in `sudo dpkg -i <package name>`

Comment: Are you saying you don't have access to apt-get somehow, or that the current instructions you're reading just don't use apt-get?

Comment: Thanks Neil. @BrianVisel When I use `apt-get`, I get a bunch of "Failed to fetch" messages. But `wget` works fine.

Comment: You may want to try doing `sudo apt-get update`.  Sometimes older package versions with security flaws don't resolve anymore.  This isn't a guaranteed fix for you, but if you can, you should use apt-get (because it *does* provide updates, whereas installing via .deb won't)

Comment: @Maru i thought you where challenging yourself. you package system sounds broken. post the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yea, `apt-get update` gives me the same messages.

Comment: ..looks like @Neil is on the right track.  You'll *definitely* want to fix your packaging system, first.

Comment: So I just asked my boss and it turns out it's the company blocking it. `wget` works because it goes through a proxy to download. But here's the output anyways: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/670e5650dd882b7e0fac

Comment: @Maru can you run this command `ping security.ubuntu.com -c 5`

Comment: Turns out I needed configure `apt-get` to use the proxy. Pinging didn't work before that. Also, thank you for telling me about the `dpkg` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks from our comments like the issue is that you're behind a proxy.  Reference this question for an answer:

[Configure proxy for APT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can use `apt-get` now.

Comment: Great!  Glad it worked for you.