# installing ansible on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, proxy, repository, add-apt-repository

I'm following this document to install ansible:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ansible-on-ubuntu-14-04

I'm try to add ansible to my ubuntu repositories list but this is what happens:

```
me@mydev:~/Documents$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ansible/ubuntu/ansible'.
ERROR: '~ansible' user or team does not exist.
me@mydev:~/Documents$
```

I've also tried to just clone the repo (following these instructions: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html)
But that fails with the following:

```
me@mydev:~/Documents/ansible$ git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
Cloning into 'ansible'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out

me@mydev:~/Documents/ansible$ ping 192.30.252.131
PING 192.30.252.131 (192.30.252.131) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.30.252.131: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=23.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.131: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=23.5 ms
^C
--- 192.30.252.131 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.466/23.511/23.557/0.159 ms
me@mydev:~/Documents/ansible$
```

As you can see, I'm getting a connection timeout error.  I tried pinging the server and it seems to be able to communicate with my box.
Not sure what else I could try.

thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I am behind a proxy.  I ran this command to identify my proxy server:

```
me@mydev:~/Documents/ansible$ export http_proxy=http://10.20.30.40:8080
```

and then to test, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and it ran fine.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, I am behind a proxy.  To test whether i'm getting out to the www, I just did an "sudo apt-get update" and it was able to update with no errors.  is that an inaccurate test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure proxy for APT?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt)

Answer (score 4):

I added the `-E` switch to my `sudo` command and it worked. Try:

```
sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
```

This moves (or copies) your environment variables, including `http_proxy` into the sudo context.

Answer (score 1):

Either there was a problem on the launchpad or you are having connection problems. It added without a problem:

```
$sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
[sudo] password for rinzwind: 
 Ansible is a radically simple IT automation platform that makes your applications and systems easier to deploy. Avoid writing scripts or custom code to deploy and update your applications— automate in a language that approaches plain English, using SSH, with no agents to install on remote systems.

http://ansible.com/
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpjhg3_1oq/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpjhg3_1oq/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 7BB9C367 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpjhg3_1oq/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 7BB9C367: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ansible, Inc." imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Comment: any suggestions on how to go about testing what the issue might be?

Comment: hmm I see you use a proxy, That is the most likely culprit

Comment: please see my Edit 1. i've added some details about how I'm setting up the proxy.  maybe that's where my problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following worked for me.

```
# Make sure the source list directory exists
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d

# Adde the Ansible sources.
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu wily main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ansible.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu wily main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ansible.list

# Install Ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
```

If you're on another release you might have to change the `wily` to match. Check at the [Ansible Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible) for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your PROXY and Firewall doesn't allow you to connect via SSH.

You could try HTTPS what is most used protocol for firewalls and proxies:

```
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
```