# sudo apt-get update not working Unable to connect to 192.168.1.254:3128

Tags: apt

Usually but not always when I try to download some few software through `apt` I have plenty of errors in the error log such as the following one:

```
Err http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-fr                
  Unable to connect to 192.168.1.254:3128:
```

Or also

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.1.254:3128:
```

Some said it was because of a proxy, but I don't use a proxy.

I did:

```
:~$ apt-config dump acquire::http
Acquire::http "";
Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.1.254:3128/";
```

and

```
:~$ grep 192.168.1.254 /etc/apt/ -R
/etc/apt/apt.conf:Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.1.254:3128/";
/etc/apt/apt.conf:Acquire::https::proxy "https://192.168.1.254:3128/";
/etc/apt/apt.conf:Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://192.168.1.254:3128/";
/etc/apt/apt.conf:Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://192.168.1.254:3128/";
grep: /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `apt-config dump acquire::http` and `grep 192.168.1.254 /etc/apt/ -R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from the output, you are using a proxy. Remove that configuration if you don't want it:

```
sudo sed -i '/192.168.1.254:3128/d' /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it was there... It seems useless as it impeded me to do hoses updates. I removed it, anyway to put it again if ever needed and do those updates through it too?

Comment: You can edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and put the lines back as you see in the output here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt