# Cannot add PPA - "user or team does not exist"

Tags: ppa

When I run this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~webupd8team/ubuntu/sublime-text-3'.
ERROR: '~webupd8team' user or team does not exist
```

My proxy settings are working properly

what's the solution?

Comment: APT seems to not work behind certain proxy types/configurations.

Comment: Did you configure apt - https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt ? If so try to manually add the repo `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main`

Comment: I think it's more simply that wepupd8team hasn't updated the ppa for bionic, the last update is almost 40 weeks old. Edit: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3 Open that link and click on "tecnical details about this ppa", you'll see it doesn't have a bionic(18.04) version

Comment: @David Foerster I don't actually know if OP is using 18.04, though, if he confirms it I'll surely post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @dsSTORM: I just saw that this question is from November and that the PPA in question had packages for all supported Ubuntu releases at the time. Nevermind then.

Comment: I just removed the unsuccessful entries from the software and updates and then retried the command and it worked.

Comment: For me it was the corporate proxy that I was connected to that was triggering that error. After I disconnected from that corporate proxy my "sudo apt" commands worked.

Answer (score 34):

I found a working solution at [add-apt-repository derrière un proxy d'entreprise](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/ppa#add-apt-repository_derriere_un_proxy_d_entreprise) (in French).

To summarize it, you have to export the env variables `HTTP(S)_PROXY`, lowercase and uppercase in your term.

Then execute:

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:...
```

The `-E` option will preserve the env vars defined above, and will enable the proxy use.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me in ubuntu 18.04 when trying to install Oracle 8 JDK. I fixed it by putting `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic main` in the Software Updater's settings (Settings > Other Software > Add...)

Comment: This worked under Windows Subsystem for Linux ( Ubuntu 19.x ) for me.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was my company's man-in-the-middle fake SSL certificate that caused this misleading error. If you are on corporate internet, you may need to install your company's SSL cert at `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/yourcompany.crt` and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates -y && sudo update-ca-certificates`

Comment: "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates -y &&  **sudo** update-ca-certificates" worked for me, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

> Running add-apt-repository without internet connection really does
> produce the same error message as in the question. One might consider
> the error message being incorrect or confusing like this as a bug
> though.

Adding the corresponding repositories is not enough unless you have an internet connection.

I fixed this by **making an internet connection** because the repositories had already been added.

Check this with: `$ ping www.google.com`

Comment: Running `add-apt-repository` without internet connection *really* does produce the same error message as in the question, so this answer is 100% valid. One might consider the error message being incorrect or confusing like this as a bug though.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thank you very much for understanding and moderating this answer. I added your comment to the body of the response. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Also, consider your VPN activity when using WSL as in general VPN's and WSL (Ubuntu) don't mix well. So if you are receiving these errors with a VPN connected, **try disabling your VPN and running the command again**. This is an odd fix that should be attempted if the above mentioned solutions aren't working for you.

More info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting under the *Bash loses network connectivity once connected to a VPN*

Comment: Thank you. Same problem for me solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `add-apt-repository` doesn't use apt proxy settings (maybe it's using `wget` under the hood). A workaround is to tun the command from a machine which is not behind a proxy and to copy the files

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ondrej_ubuntu_php.gpg
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list
```

to the other machine.

Comment: …or simply use the manual method described on Launchpad for each PPA.