# Cannot add PPA: user or team does not exist Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, ppa

Hi I Installed a new Ubuntu 18.04 for the first time in my VM and trying to run below command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
```

It throws below error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ethereum/ubuntu/ethereum'.
ERROR: '~ethereum' user or team does not exist.
```

The command

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

runs fine.

I tried to reinstall all ca-certs but nothing helped. there is no proxy configured as well.

In fact any PPA repository I try to add it throws the same error user or team does not exits.

Any guidance in this regard will be of great help as it has become a showstopper for us.

Comment: Add manually, see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/971877/cannot-add-ppa-user-or-team-does-not-exist/1036627