# apt-get upgrade Error 403 forbidden

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

sudo apt-get update works fine, but when I run sudo apt-get upgrade I get these errors: (NOTE: I have already changed the download server from source.list to archive.ubuntu.com instead of pt.archive.ubuntu.com)

```
/etc/apt# sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libdrm2 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils apport cloud-guest-utils distro-info-data gcc-5-base grub-common grub-legacy-ec2 grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common hdparm ifupdown libicu55
  libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libpci3 libperl5.22 libplymouth4 libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libseccomp2 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 linux-base
  lshw lxcfs lxd lxd-client mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 open-vm-tools openssl patch pciutils perl perl-base
  perl-modules-5.22 plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text python-apt-common python3-apport python3-apt python3-distupgrade python3-problem-report python3.5 python3.5-minimal snap-confine snapd
  sosreport ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-release-upgrader-core wget xdg-user-dirs
63 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.7 MB/67.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,140 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython3.5 amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Ign:2 http/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python3.5 amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4
Ign:3 http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython3.5-stdlib amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4
Err:1 http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython3.5 amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

......................

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
E: Failed to fetch http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/libpython3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/python3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/python3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Thanks!
R.L.

Comment: You may have problems with your internet, or you may be using proxy. Apt uses its own proxy, so to configure it, refer this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt

Answer (score 1):

Try seeing if your file is corrupted in your local apt repository. Reset it using

```
sudo rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: No, it didn't worked!!! The problem stays the same!!!

Comment: Sometimes the packages are held back because they require the installation of new packages and sudo apt-get upgrade does not install new packages.
To install the required new packages you can run
Code:
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
To note this only updates the current release and does not upgrade that to another, newer, release
(like upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, it will not do that)

Basically apt-get upgrade only updates packages that exist on the system. But will never install new packages.
apt-get dist-upgrade will install new packages if the updates require them.

Comment: I've done that but... problem remains... Error 403 forbidden!!! What else can I try?

Comment: See if this article might help: https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-to-16-10/

Comment: Just summarizing the guide. 

sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo nano /etc/upgrade-manager/release-upgrades

prompt=normal
sudo do-release-upgrade

Should do it for you.