# installing gnome shell extensions timeout

Tags: virtualbox, software-center, proxy, gnome-shell-extension

I have Ubuntu installed on VirtualBox and behind proxy. I have set automatic proxy configuration. All applications are able to connect to internet.

However Gnome Shell extensions are not getting installed. With Ubuntu Software center, it shows a timeout error though other applications are getting installed. From Browser on https://extensions.gnome.org, on-off button seems to do nothing (browser extension and chrome-gnome-shell are installed).

With manual proxy setting, Ubuntu Software center throws  `GDbus.error:org.gnome.shell.downloadinfoerror:4`

Can someone help me to fix this?

Note: `sudo apt install <other apps>` works without any error.

Comment: APT doesn't work behind a proxy or need configuration: https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia APT is working with automatic proxy configuration. No problem with APT.