# Kubernetes installation failing - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, kubernetes

I am trying to install Kubernetes (kubectl) on Ubuntu 16.04 (x64) by following the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl). I am behind some proxy at work and I am sure that is the reason for the failure. I know there are a bunch of related questions out there but I have already tried any suggestion I could find. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Currently, I am stuck at getting apt update to work. It is failing with -

```
W: The repository 'https://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

I have tried multiple things here -
Updated my `apt.conf`(at `/etc/apt/apt.conf`) with

```
Acquire::https::packages.cloud.google.com::Verify-Peer "false";
```

I also tried by specifying the above as a command line argument -

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::https::packages.cloud.google.com::Verify-Peer=false
```

I have tried running `apt-get update` with `--allow-unauthenticated` & `--allow-insecure-repositories` but somehow `apt-secure` is still ignoring all these instructions. I went through the man-page for `apt-secure` but couldn't find anything wrong with the options I specified.

I have updated keys using -

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 6A030B21BA07F4FB
```

I have updated my CA certs. I have ran - `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` to remove all the lists.

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`

```
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
```

Comment: [`apt` need to be configured](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt) even if you have `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable correctly configured. BTW if you are trying Kubernetes locally take a look to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109537/349837) answer.

Answer (score 14):

There will be a redirection issue sometimes.

Use the source below will solve this.

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ kubernetes-xenial main
```

---

Update in 2024.3.28: **use a new URL**.

```
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/ /
```

Get the `gpg` key if absent:

```
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg
```

The official document is [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/08/15/pkgs-k8s-io-introduction/#how-to-migrate-deb). It works for me.

Quote from [Installing kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/):

> Note: The legacy package repositories (apt.kubernetes.io and yum.kubernetes.io) have been **deprecated and frozen starting from September 13, 2023**. Using the new package repositories hosted at **pkgs.k8s.io** is strongly recommended and required in order to install Kubernetes versions released **after September 13, 2023**. The deprecated legacy repositories, and their contents, might be removed at any time in the future and without a further notice period. The new package repositories provide downloads for Kubernetes versions starting with v1.24.0.

Comment: Now it is 2021 and the workaround still works. Thanks for it. Ubuntu/Google did not bother to fix the issue with their official guide "How to install kubectl".

Comment: This does not work anymore

Comment: @AmoghJahagirdar Did you find a working solution?

Comment: No, my flow already involved using gcloud sdk, so I am able to install kubectl from within, couldn't resolve with via this method

Answer (score 3):

For Amogh and Guru,

The reason this doesn't work anymore, as of January 31st 2024, is that K8s changed repo locations. See https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/08/15/pkgs-k8s-io-introduction/#how-to-migrate

To deal with this, I have:

1.) removed the old source

which was: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt_kubernetes_io.list
which contained

```
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
```

2.) added the new source
See their directions above, but short version is:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg

sudo apt-get update
```

note the new repos ARE version sensitive, and you need to set the version appropriately. The above is for v1.28

Answer (score 2):

For latest ubuntu version where deb command is not found

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ kubernetes-xenial main
```

And for any errors for the packages add the gpg key

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then execute

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: this is works great on ubuntu 22 ! better than official documentation on kubernetes website (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/)