# How to install Kubernetes Locally via Minikube

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, kubernetes

Trying to learn more about Kubernetes I tried to install a standalone instance. If you try to run `minikube` terminal? [suggest installing it through snap](https://snapcraft.io/minikube).

```
sudo snap install minikube kubectl
```

- `snap info minikube`

  > Minikube is a tool that makes it easy to run Kubernetes locally. Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a VM on your laptop for users looking to try out Kubernetes or develop with it day-to-day.
- `snap info kubectl`

  > kubectl is a command line interface for running commands against Kubernetes

But that let me with this error:

```
$ minikube start
There is a newer version of minikube available (v0.32.0).  Download it here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.32.0
To disable this notification, add WantUpdateNotification: False to the json config file at /home/pablo/snap/minikube/4/.minikube/config
(you may have to create the file config.json in this folder if you have no previous configuration)
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
E0113 21:27:07.861621   12532 start.go:83] Error starting host: Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address. Retrying.
E0113 21:27:07.876969   12532 start.go:83] Error starting host: Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address. Retrying.
E0113 21:27:07.892771   12532 start.go:83] Error starting host: Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address. Retrying.
E0113 21:27:07.892806   12532 start.go:89] Error starting host:  Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address
Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address
Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address
```

I tried:

- Almost all suggestions on Github issues: [278](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/278), [867](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/867), [927](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/927), [2294](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2294), [2424](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2424).
- Installing (already there) `libvirt-bin` (`libvirt-clients` `libvirt-daemon`)
- `sudo virsh -c qemu:///system net-start default`

Maybe [not ready for prime time](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506160950/http://archive.lug.boulder.co.us/Week-of-Mon-20180827/045590.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a working solution, removing the snap package (`sudo snap remove minikube`) and then following one of the [official guides](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) keeping `kubectl`:

```sh
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
&& sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

Tested with `kubectl version` and

```sh
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    master   25m   v1.12.4
```

To run the dashboard just

```sh
minikube dashboard
```

Alternatively you could try [**microk8s**](https://microk8s.io/) (add-ons, ARM, multi-node), [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) or [k3s](https://k3s.io/). You might be also interested in [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/nomad-vs-kubernetes).

Comment: Worked for me "snap remove minikube"

Comment: so minikube snap actually isn't ready for primetime?