# apt-get update unable to access us archive repository

Tags: package-management, updates, repository

as the title states apt-get update is  unable to access us archive repository, previously was not able to install anything from any four of the repositories, but this problem was resolved simply by rebooting my system, but I am having trouble installing vagrant at the moment, and the output cites things I am missing from the archive repository.

also note that for the vagrant install, I have already tried the recommendation in the output to append --fix-missing to the install command, and still no love, output reports the same problem.

I realise that this might be the same issue maybe involved and is very likely to be the DNS server as a user explained here [Updating the apt-get command in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105366/updating-the-apt-get-command-in-the-terminal)
In a previous question I asked, and for some reason my computer only has wifi issues when I follow the prompts from the software updater to download an update.

If this is too vague let me know and I will insert my terminal output into the question many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: can you post the error message you get from apt, as well as the content of  etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: ok no problem I will update this question tonight with those details