# not able to reach 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' through terminal

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, proxy

Why terminal is showing `Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'` but the browser is able to reach that website. I am running ubuntu 18.04 on vmware behind the proxy server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure proxy for APT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by configuring the proxy for apt.check answer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt) answer