# Update Ubuntu behind proxy

Tags: updates, squid

I have a PC with Ubuntu 20.04. This PC is behind a Squid proxy. I want to update it. I tried both graphic and cli commands but it is impossible. If I add proxy parameters to Network I can browse the Internet.
The proxy is installed in a pfSense firewall.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you looked at questions with answers such as https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt which discuss exactly this?