# Setup Ubuntu updates via a proxy

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, vpn, proxy

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and sharing my phone internet connection which is using http tunneling, with my Ubuntu laptop. The app on the phone provides a proxy IP and a port to connect to it's internet. I have added those proxy IP and port on Ubuntu network proxy settings

[image]

I can use that Internet connection to browse the Internet and works well on the browser but, cannot use the terminal to update Ubuntu. It gives me this bad request error.

```
nuwan@myUbuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                     
Hit:2 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                
Hit:3 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                            
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                           
  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease           
  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease     
  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
Get:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
Get:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,090 B]
Reading package lists... Done         
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 192.168.43.69 44355]
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I found some [related questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt) like this, but they didn't help my problem. what is the problem here? (IP address differs from the one in the image because I removed the image and re added code with new result)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting.

Comment: @muru Sure. Thanks

Comment: @muru I am Done.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is this:

Edit your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.43.104:44355";
```

Comment: actuallty this did not help with updates