# Ubuntu software not working with proxy settings

Tags: proxy

I am currently using Ubuntu 21.04. My college has provided the proxy settings to connect to the internet, but it only has the host address and the port no. It doesn't have username and password.

With these settings, i am able to use internet, but ubuntu software and updates are not working. It is saying "check internet connection".

Comment: Ask the college IT if it is blocked.

Comment: Most likely what @David is saying is true as i have also experienced that. In my company I could browse internet but not able to download any python or other packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure proxy for APT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt)

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto, I will go through the methods mentioned in the post

Comment: Ok @David , I will try asking college as well