# Using ethernet LAN with a proxy server. Ubuntu terminal not connecting to internet but browser is connecting

Tags: networking, command-line, apt, internet, proxy

I assume the terminal is unable to connect to internet since when I use 'sudo apt update', I get.... Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'..
Also, ping 8.8.8.8 gives no result.

I am unable to update the os at all after I installed it since I am unable to do sudo apt update.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes I am behind a proxy

Comment: There's your answer. More info:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt