# In ubuntu server apt-get update showing proxy server error

Tags: command-line, server

I am trying to update packages on Ubuntu server 22.10 which is running on a Raspberry Pi 4B, that is being used as a remote server. There is no error in the DNS I tried ping google.com and it is working properly.

```
--- google.com ping statistics --- 9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 8013ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.560/6.795/6.941/0.126
```

I'm not sure about my UFW firewall port. And do let me know if there's been any mistake in opening or closing any ports.

ufw firewall status

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active


To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10000                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9200                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
10000 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9200 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Error that it's showing

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/server:/10/Ubuntu_21.10  InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-backports InRelease
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/server:/10/Ubuntu_21.10  InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-backports InRelease
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/server:/10/Ubuntu_21.10  InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-backports InRelease
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-security InRelease
Err:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/server:/10/Ubuntu_21.10  InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
Err:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
Err:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/kinetic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/kinetic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/kinetic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/kinetic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/server:/10/Ubuntu_21.10/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/kinetic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'proxyserver'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

No proxy server is created which has been checked by using this code of lines

```
echo "$http_proxy"

echo "$https_proxy"

env | grep proxy
```

All the above shows no output, and nothing is there even in sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.

I want to get it back to the normal way it used to get updated and upgraded, and I want to delete unwanted UFW ports, which can be harmful for the server's security.

Edit::::::
For further discussion and solution please check
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484973&p=14136226#post14136226

Comment: You've added a PPA that supports only LTS releases (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) yet aren't using a LTS release?  You've not said what *architecture* you're using (*relevant due to ports usage*)   *Your output appears to contain more than a single problem; I picked the first 'easy' one I saw*

Comment: @guiverc I'm sorry I did not check regarding the LTS part.  So this is the main error mentioned above. I'm utterly clueless regarding what must be done as an update and upgrade.

Comment: @guiverc I tried pin google.com and it is working properly

--- google.com ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 8013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.560/6.795/6.941/0.126 ms

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. I did make changes as you mentioned and is there anything else you need please let me know.

Comment: @guiverc I would like to say that the error is still not solved and I do need your help on this issue :(

Comment: Please check the answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt  if somewhere a proxy is set for apt on your system.