# apt update error only with non-official ppas

Tags: apt, 22.04, ppa

On a computer which is behind a proxy ([appropriately configured](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt) I hope), after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 then 22.04:

- updating/upgrading from the official Ubuntu repositories works fine, so I assume there is no issue with the network configuration
- But updating any non official PPAs always give an error, see below.

```
> sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/Ubuntu_22.04  InRelease  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                            
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/Ubuntu_22.04  InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/Ubuntu_22.04  InRelease
Err:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                              
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 134.226.56.7 8080]
Err:2 https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/Ubuntu_22.04  InRelease                                                                                                           
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 134.226.56.7 8080]
Fetched 109 kB in 7s (15.3 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 134.226.56.7 8080]
W: Failed to fetch https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/Ubuntu_22.04/InRelease  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 134.226.56.7 8080]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It looks like a network error, right? If so why does it happen only with non-official PPAs? Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Now I see something all ppa's has https and not http.

Comment: @nobody Thank you very much for this subtle observations: replacing the `https` with `http` in the sources made the mozilla ppa work. However it didn't work with the owncloud ppa, still the same error. Also I don't understand what happened: is it not supposed to be `https`? If so, why did I have `https` after adding a ppa normally with `add-apt-repository`?

Comment: Please can you try `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=false update` I do not want to add this repo on my system for tests. I do not use add-apt-repository I always add ppa's manual.

Comment: @nobody I tried the command but it still gives the same error. I also tried another ppa with `http` and it worked fine, so maybe the remaining problem is specific to the owncloud ppa for some reason. Thank you anyway, your tips were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nobody's comment, replacing all the `https` with `http` in the failing non-official PPAs addresses found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xxx` solves the issue for most repositories.

This worked with at least three different PPAs, but the owncloud PPA still gets an error. There might be a [specific error](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/10541) with their server.